# Why does the main statement in a mrjob Python program accept only one line of code?

Tags: python, indentation, mrjob

I want to know how long a mrjob program runs. However, I get an `unindent does not match any outer indentation level` error if I put in `time.time()` before and after `MRWord.run()`, and I couldn't find any documentation about this. What am I missing?

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWord(MRJob):

  def mapper(self, _, line):
    x = line.split()
    yield x[0], 1

  def reducer(self, word, counts):
    yield word, sum(counts)

if __name__ == '__main__':

  t0 = time.time() 

  MRWord.run()

  print time.time() - t0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the indent before `t0 = time.time()`, did you mixed space and tab?